# Code behaving differently when i return 'this' in the function

Tags: javascript, oop, return, prototype, this

I have created an object with an object literal and then created another object with `Object.create(car)`.

```
var car = {

init: function(sound) { 
    this.sound = sound
    return this
}, 
makeSound: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
}}

var aventador = Object.create(car).init("whatever")
aventador.makeSound()
```

The thing i want to know is that when i return `this` in `init` function, i can use the code like this:
`var aventador = Object.create(car).init("Whatever")
aventador.makeSound()` and it console logs **Whatever**

but when i dont return `this` in the `init` function, it says **undefined**
and when i do something like the following:
`var aventador = Object.create(car)
aventador.init("Whatever")
aventador.makeSound()` it works even without returning `this` in the `init` function.

please explain in details whats happening?

Comment: Uh, you're assigning the return value of the `.init(…)` call to `aventador`. So what else would you expect to happen?

Comment: I mean i can do `var aventador = Object.create(car).init("Whatever")` and 
then call the method `aventador.makeSound()` and it gives me the result, but when i dont return `this` in the `init(...)` function i get an undefined doings the same thing as above... why is that?

Comment: Obviously because `init` returns `undefined` when you don't return anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are properties of an object.

When you return `this` and use that return value, you get that object. You can then call another function on that object.

When you don't have a `return` statement, you get `undefined`. `undefined` is not that object and the functions are not properties of `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

check this, the above statement having 2 parts an object variable called **aventador** it is assigned with the statement `Object.create(car).init("whatever")`. In your initial code this statement returning **this** as the object context. So **aventador** will get an object instance and it will call the **makeSound** method.
In the second method you are actualy creating the parent object using the statement `var aventador = Object.create(car)`. This will automaticaly create an Object of type car and aventador have an instance of car. so aventador can be used to call both **init** and **makeSound** method using the object.

Answer (score 0):

The default return value of a function is always undefined. In your case, if init() doesn't **return this**, then it returns undefined. Obviously when you access something with undefined always throws an error.

Hope that answers your doubt